# Redux/React HMR <Provider> error

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, typescript2.0, hot-module-replacement

I'm trying to set up HMR with react-hot-loader v3 on the Redux counter example (ported to typescript).

The HMR actually seems to work, in that the page updates, but the first update always throws `` warning.js?8f69:14 <Provider> does not support changing `store` on the fly. It is most likely that you see this error because you updated to Redux 2.x and React Redux 2.x which no longer hot reload reducers automatically. See https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v2.0.0 for the migration instructions. ``
Oddly enough, subsequent updates do NOT throw this (and continue to work) until I reload the page.

I believe I've set things up the way all the docs say to, and I can not figure out why this is happening. I'm hoping someone's come across this.

**index.ts**

```
const store: Store<IAppState> = configureStore();
const rootEl = document.getElementById('root');

let render = () => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <AppContainer>
            <Root store={ store }/>
        </AppContainer>,
        rootEl
    );
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    if ((module as any).hot) {
        (module as any).hot.accept(() => {
            setTimeout(render);
        });
    }
}

render();
```

**root.ts**

```
let Root = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') ?
    RootProd :
    RootDev;

export default Root;
```

**root.dev.ts**

```
export default class RootDev extends React.Component<IRootProps, void> {
  render() {
    const { store } = this.props;

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <div>
          <CounterApp />
          <DevTools />
        </div>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

**configureStore.ts**

```
let configureStore = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') ?
    configureStoreProd :
    configureStoreDev;

export default configureStore;
```

**configureStore.dev.ts**

```
const composeEnhancers = (window as any).__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const enhancer = composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(thunk.default),
    DevTools.instrument(),
    persistState(
        window.location.href.match(/[?&]debug_session=([^&#]+)\b/) ?
            window.location.href.match(/[?&]debug_session=([^&#]+)\b/)[0] :
            'defaultDevSession'
    )
);

export default function configureStoreDev():Store<IAppState> {
    const store = createStore<IAppState>(rootReducer, enhancer);

    if ((<any>module).hot) {
        (<any>module).hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
            console.log('replaceReducer');
            store.replaceReducer(require('../reducers').rootReducer)
        });
    }

    return store;
}
```

In case the pasted code is not sufficient, entire project is here: https://github.com/japhar81/redux_template

Comment: I had a look at the project codebase, and found no scripts for starting it up. How can I run it?

Comment: I actually fixed it, but if you want to try it.. cd <clone dir> then ```npm install && ./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config ./webpack.server.js && node dist/server.js```

Comment: @XeroxDucati could you share what you ended up doing that fixed the issue? Running into this myself and it's not immediately apparent what you did to fix it from the source.

Comment: @Krustal i did this in createStore:  const store = createStore<IAppState>(require('../reducers').rootReducer, enhancer);

        /* istanbul ignore next */
        if ((<any>module).hot) {
            (<any>module).hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
                store.replaceReducer(require('../reducers').rootReducer);
            });
        }

Comment: @XeroxDucati thanks for sharing that was definitely the solution. I'd be curious how to do this and still pass initialState as the second argument as that seems to be the root of my problem. If you post the above as an answer I'd be happy to supply the up vote.

Comment: @Krustal I'm setting initialState in my createStore call and it seems to work fine with the hot reload..